# What advantage is there in pairing when programming that there isn't when pairing in other jobs?

Tags: pair-programming

Surely two people sitting together doing countless other jobs you would see the same benefits.  Why has programming been singled out for this practice?

Comment: I think programming has been "singled out" for this because you're much more likely to read about "pair programming" than "pair anything else"--you are, after all, a programmer yourself!

Answer (score 12):

It actually hasn't been singled out at all. Think about the terminology: **driver and navigator**. Commercial aviation has long benefitted from this technique with pilots and copilots. Most jobs where detail is extremely important can benefit from working in pairs. You will never see a brain surgeon alone in a surgery room hacking away; the team around him are checking over the work, making sure the surgeon is not forgetting anything (like a sponge).

Comment: +1 for providing the actual examples in other professions.

Answer (score 7):

Any job that requires more thinking than actual manual work benefits from pairing.

Comment: Can you give examples? I can think about lots of counterexamples: Mathematicians normally work alone and only meet to discuss stuff from time to time.